# Swift - How to check if Rtmp url is valid?

Tags: ios, swift, url, stream, rtmp

I wanted to know how to check if RTMP url is valid and exist or not ? If people can watch my stream and the rtmp url doesn"t return an error like 404.

For example i have : `rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:440/rtmp/xxxxxxxx`

I know how to check simple URL like `https://google.fr` but to be honest i don't have any idea for RTMP url

Best regard !

Comment: I assume exactly the same as any other url

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already tried, but don't work

Comment: it's just a URL, try `if let url = URL(string: "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:440/rtmp/xxxxxxxx") { print("its valid" } else { print("not valid") }` otherwise you could use a URL regex pattern, lots of those online

Comment: Ah sorry maybe i misspoke. When i said if my RTMP url is valid or not, i wanted to know if my RTML url work or not, if people can access the stream, not a 404 error for example. I'm going to edit, sorry it's my bad

Comment: Fair enough but now I don’t understand what this has to do with programming, you want to do this from your app?

Comment: Yes exactly ! It's possible to do this from my app ?

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression for validation

`const str = "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:440/rtmp/xxxxxxxx";`

`const regx = /^((rtmps?):\/\/.*\/.*)?$/;`

`patt.test(str) ? console.log('valid') : console.log('invalid')`

The test() method tests for a match in a string.
This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns false.